# laravel-5.8:Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi I make a form to upload pics in Laravel but when I open the form then it shows error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

blade file:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.product.alternateimages') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add-new-post">
    @csrf
    <strong class="text-muted d-block mb-2 mt-5">Upload Product Image</strong>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
        <input type="file" name="product_alt_img[]" class="form-control mb-2 btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-1 @error('product_image') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('product_image') }}" id="" placeholder=""> </div>
        @error('product_image')
          <div class="small text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
    </div>
</form>
```

function:

```
    public function alternateimages(Request $request)
    {
        $altimgs = new Product;
        $altimgs->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $files = $request->file('product_alt_img');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $images = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move(public_path('images/backend_images/product_images'), $images);
          $altimgs->product_alt_img = $images;
        }
        $altimgs->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product Images has been added successfully');   
    }
```

Comment: based on this `product_alt_img[]` looks like you're trying to upload multiple files ? If yes please add foreach loop inside of `alternateimages` method, i think  $paths is returning array of images so you need to iterate it and handle each files separately.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: public function alternateimages(Request $request)
    {
        $altimgs = new Product;
        $altimgs->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $files = $request->file('product_alt_img');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $images = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move(public_path('images/backend_images/product_images'), $images);
          $altimgs->product_alt_img = $images;
        }
        $altimgs->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product Images has been added successfully');   
    }

Comment: I added foreach loop but now it says Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: it might your $files variables be null at some cases, try `foreach ($files??[] as $file)`

Comment: Please come in to the chatting room for further discussion, so that we can resolve it asap. @pro

Comment: @Vipertecpro actually m trying to add alternate images to products which is not happening

Comment: how to join chat room because its link is not appearing

Comment: Here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198757/discussion-between-emeka-mbah-and-pro

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change `product_alt_img[]` to `product_alt_img` if you are uploading a single file.

```
<input type="file" name="product_alt_img" class="form-control mb-2 btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-1 @error('product_image') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('product_image') }}" id="" placeholder="">
```

Else if wish to upload multiple file, you may have to modify your controller method.

```
 public function alternateimages(Request $request)
{
    $altimgs = new Product;
    $altimgs->product_id = $request->product_id;

    //fetch an array of product_alt_img
    $files = $request->product_alt_img;

    //go over each Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile instance
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $image = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        ....
    }

    ....  
}
```

NB: A more eloquent solution is to have a separate table for storing products images

Comment: I wants to upload multiple pics how to modify controller

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: public function alternateimages(Request $request)
    {
        $altimgs = new Product;
        $altimgs->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $files = $request->file('product_alt_img');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $images = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move(public_path('images/backend_images/product_images'), $images);
          $altimgs->product_alt_img = $images;
        }
        $altimgs->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product Images has been added successfully');   
    }

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I modified my answer ` $paths = $request->product_alt_img`  ... this should be your field name `name="product_alt_img[]"` since its multiple files

Comment: it still says: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: this should be your field name name="product_alt_img[]" since its multiple files.. try to check content `dd($request->product_alt_img)`

Comment: try `dd($request->all())` check the content of product_alt_img

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198757/discussion-between-emeka-mbah-and-pro).